# Multiscroll.js plugin - right side works late

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiscroll.js

This plugin is great, but I think the right side lags.

I am trying to use this plugin with bootstrap for a website. I have used a fullscreen carousel and I used the solution described in this site http://reverzo.tymberry.com/ to do so.

My problem is that i am trying to make a full screen carousel by taking two carousel on left and right side which cuts and looks as one.

This is my site http://tantra-gyan.in/nitpl/#first

The carousel is not synched well and right side lags.

Comment: sory i forgot to post the plugin i am using .this is the plugin

Comment: http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/

Comment: ooops... i am so sry

Comment: http://www.tantra-gyan.in/nitpl/#first heres my project

Comment: What have you tried to fix the problem? Do you have any clue which part of the code is causing this? Share some experiences diagnosing the problem.

Comment: idont know .....first i thought it would be because images are heavy i used optimized imaes, still it lags...I am very close to this....and this can be a good stuff for other programmers as well if it gets solved

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

// for synching testimonials carousel on home page
$('.carousel-sync').carousel('cycle');
$('.carousel-sync').on('click', '.carousel-control[data-slide]', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel($(this).data('slide'));
});


});